# How to implement emoji in textarea similar to gmail and facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would I go about this? Are they images?

How can I make it so that when the user types ':D' it turns into a face emoji? 
A general explanation would be great. I have no idea how you can put images in textareas.

Comment: Emojis are not images, they are characters. So you could simply have a script that look for ' :D ' and replace it by 

Answer (score 2):

Emojis are just unicode, not images, so they can be used as text. To change their look, use a different font:

[image: Extracted from http://www.businessinsider.com/unicode-emoji-chart-2015-12]

#### Extracted from http://www.businessinsider.com/unicode-emoji-chart-2015-12

---

But they aren't on (fisical) keyboards, so what some services do is to put a lot of buttons with their corresponding emoji so you can type them easily.

But what YounesM said is also true:

> ... you could simply have a script that look for ' :D ' and replace it
>   by

Other services, instead of filling a `div` with `button`s, run a script when you create or edit a post/question/answer/comment/other for replacing specific substrings with emoji.

Comment: Do you know any free fonts that have these faces? I read that I would use something like this ':smile:' But it didn't work with regular fonts.